# Mysql spliting and adding a column based on order status

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

Here is my query which I want to modify

```
select 
o.orders_id, 
o.customers_id, 
o.customers_name, 
s.orders_status_name, 
ot.text as order_total, 
ot.value as value,
datediff(now(), payment_data_read_status) as numdaysleft, 
sum(ifnull(op.paid_total, 0)) paid_total 
from orders o 
join orders_total ot 
on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id 
join orders_status s 
on o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
left outer join ( select orders_id, sum(ifnull(paid_amount, 0)) as paid_total from orders_payment where confirm_payment = '1' group by orders_id ) op on op.orders_id = o.orders_id where ot.class = 'ot_total' and s.language_id = '1' and round(ot.value,2) != round(ifnull(op.paid_total, 0), 2) 
GROUP by o.customers_id 
ORDER BY paid_total DESC
```

Each customer has its own orders with different statuses like orders complete, injecting, waiting for payment to confirm etc, What I want to achieve is to sum the value of `ot.value` for all the orders of each customer with `s.orders_status_name`= "Order Complete" and show them in a new column as 'completed_orders_sum'. Similarly the orders which are not in "Order Complete" status should add up `ot.value` and show in new column as 'incompleted_orders_sum'

here is the data for each client

[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle (PL/SQL)?

Comment: I am using mysql

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (E.g. I can't read that tiny text....)

Comment: click on the image it will zoom

Comment: @jarlh its just a demo data. I dont think it will be of any use for copy pasting. Thats why I posted image rather than text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a

```
sum(case when s.orders_status_name= "Order Complete" 
      then ot.value
      else 0
end) as completed_orders_sum
```

.

```
select 
o.orders_id, 
o.customers_id, 
o.customers_name, 
s.orders_status_name, 
ot.text as order_total, 
sum(case when s.orders_status_name= "Order Complete" 
      then ot.value
      else 0
end ) as completed_orders_sum
datediff(now(), payment_data_read_status) as numdaysleft, 
sum(ifnull(op.paid_total, 0)) paid_total 
from orders o 
join orders_total ot 
on o.orders_id = ot.orders_id 
join orders_status s 
on o.orders_status = s.orders_status_id 
left outer join ( select orders_id, sum(ifnull(paid_amount, 0)) as paid_total 
                        from orders_payment 
                        where confirm_payment = '1' group by orders_id ) op on op.orders_id = o.orders_id 
                              where ot.class = 'ot_total' and s.language_id = '1' and round(ot.value,2) != round(ifnull(op.paid_total, 0), 2) 
GROUP by o.customers_id
```

Comment: Thanks. It Worked